# Updating from Windows CryptDecrypt() to NCryptDecrypt() returns NTE_INVALID_PARAMETER(0x80090027) or STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL(0xC0000001)?

Tags: c++, cryptography, cng

Currently updating from Windows CryptDecrypt() [API is deprecated] to NCryptDecrypt() [Cryptography Next Generation].

The minimal sample code below tries to encrypt/decrypt using RSA 1024-bit.

Running with Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, it outputs the error `NTE_INVALID_PARAMETER` (0x80090027)

```
Failed Decrypt NCryptDecrypt. Error -2146893785
```

or randomly `STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL` (0xc0000001)

```
Failed Decrypt NCryptDecrypt. Error -1073741823
```

Encryption seems okay as no errors are generated, but decryption fails on `NCryptDecrypt`?

```
#define WIN32_NO_STATUS
#include <windows.h>
#undef WIN32_NO_STATUS
#include <winternl.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ncrypt.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ncrypt.lib")

//https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_rsakey_blob

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct MyRSAPublicBlob {
    BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB blob{};
    BYTE exponent[3] = {};
    BYTE modulus[128] = {};

    MyRSAPublicBlob(const std::vector<BYTE>& mod, const std::vector<BYTE>& exp, ULONG modulusSize) : blob{}
    {
        blob.BitLength = modulusSize * 8;
        blob.Magic = BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_MAGIC;
        blob.cbModulus = modulusSize;
        blob.cbPublicExp = static_cast<DWORD>(exp.size());
        blob.cbPrime1 = 0;
        blob.cbPrime2 = 0;

        memcpy(exponent, exp.data(), exp.size());
        memcpy(modulus, mod.data(), mod.size());
    }

    MyRSAPublicBlob() : blob{} { }
};
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct MyRSAPrivateBlob {
    BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB blob{};
    BYTE exponent[3] = {};
    BYTE modulus[128] = {};
    BYTE prime1[64] = {};
    BYTE prime2[64] = {};

    MyRSAPrivateBlob(const std::vector<BYTE>& mod, const std::vector<BYTE>& exp, ULONG modulusSize,
        const std::vector<BYTE>& p, const std::vector<BYTE>& q) : blob{}
    {
        blob.Magic = BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_MAGIC;
        blob.BitLength = modulusSize * 8;
        blob.cbModulus = modulusSize;
        blob.cbPublicExp = static_cast<DWORD>(exp.size());
        blob.cbPrime1 = static_cast<DWORD>(p.size());
        blob.cbPrime2 = static_cast<DWORD>(q.size());

        memcpy(exponent, exp.data(), exp.size());
        memcpy(modulus, mod.data(), mod.size());
        memcpy(prime1, p.data(), p.size());
        memcpy(prime2, q.data(), q.size());
    }

    MyRSAPrivateBlob() : blob{} { }
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int RSA1024_encrypt(char* plainText, int plainExtent, char* cipherText, int cipherExtent, struct MyRSAPublicBlob keyBlob)
{
    SECURITY_STATUS stat;
    NCRYPT_PROV_HANDLE hProv;
    NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey;
    DWORD numEncryptedBytes = 0;

    stat = NCryptOpenStorageProvider(&hProv, MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != stat) {
        std::cout << "Failed NCryptOpenStorageProvider. Error " << stat;
        return 0;
    }

    stat = NCryptImportKey(hProv, NULL, BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB, NULL, &hKey, (PBYTE)&keyBlob.blob, sizeof(keyBlob),0);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != stat) {
        std::cout << "Failed NCryptImportKey. Error " << stat;
        return 0;
    }

    stat = NCryptEncrypt(hKey,(PBYTE)plainText, plainExtent, NULL, (PBYTE)cipherText, cipherExtent, &numEncryptedBytes, NCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1_FLAG);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != stat) {
        std::cout << "Failed NCryptEncrypt. Error " << stat;
        return 0;
    }

    return numEncryptedBytes;
}


int RSA1024_decrypt(char* plainText, int plainExtent, char* cipherText, int cipherExtent, struct MyRSAPrivateBlob keyBlob)
{
    SECURITY_STATUS stat;
    NCRYPT_PROV_HANDLE hProv;
    NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey;
    DWORD numDecryptedBytes = 0;

    stat = NCryptOpenStorageProvider(&hProv, MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != stat) {
        std::cout << "Failed Decrypt NCryptOpenStorageProvider. Error " << stat;
        return 0;
    }

    stat = NCryptImportKey(hProv, NULL, BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB, NULL, &hKey, (PBYTE)&keyBlob.blob, sizeof(keyBlob),0);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != stat) {
        std::cout << "Failed Decrypt NCryptImportKey. Error " << stat;
        return 0;
    }

    // NTE_INVALID_PARAMETER(0x80090027) or STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL(0xC0000001)
    stat = NCryptDecrypt(hKey,(PBYTE)cipherText,cipherExtent, NULL, (PBYTE)plainText, plainExtent, &numDecryptedBytes, NCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1_FLAG);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != stat) {
        std::cout << "Failed Decrypt NCryptDecrypt. Error " << stat;
        return 0;
    }

    return numDecryptedBytes;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr BYTE publicExponent[] = {
        0x1, 0x0, 0x1
    };

    constexpr BYTE modulus[] = {
        0xb0,0x71,0x76,0x5d,0xef,0x1b,0x6f,0x3c,
        0xf2,0xde,0x31,0x8c,0xa1,0x66,0x50,0xee,
        0x01,0x96,0x64,0x7e,0x1d,0x3e,0xac,0xa9,
        0xad,0x06,0x31,0x56,0x97,0x1d,0x3c,0x71,
        0xeb,0xcc,0xef,0xa1,0x24,0xb0,0xb7,0x0a,
        0x33,0xf7,0x29,0x00,0x36,0x4c,0x4c,0x72,
        0xd9,0x88,0x39,0xa8,0xf6,0x27,0xc9,0x24,
        0xfc,0x4d,0x38,0xb3,0x03,0x06,0x56,0xe3,
        0xfc,0x67,0x6a,0xb3,0xe2,0xf1,0xc1,0x4a,
        0xf9,0xd2,0xab,0xdd,0xae,0xd0,0x2e,0xca,
        0x11,0x41,0x32,0xd8,0x07,0xff,0x3a,0xb2,
        0x27,0x3c,0xb9,0xcd,0x64,0x4f,0xbd,0x23,
        0xb6,0x01,0x77,0x33,0xd8,0x6f,0x5a,0x84,
        0xaa,0x9c,0x21,0x0b,0xd8,0xdb,0xe7,0xe2,
        0x7e,0x9b,0x6a,0x7b,0x4c,0x5e,0xae,0x1d,
        0xda,0x78,0x02,0x87,0xeb,0xe6,0x4f,0x7b
    };

    constexpr BYTE privateExponent[] = {
        0x1e,0xbc,0x24,0xfa,0x47,0xe4,0x67,0x84,
        0x1e,0x6a,0x46,0x07,0x51,0x36,0x19,0x72,
        0xdc,0x23,0xee,0x6d,0x69,0x7a,0xb9,0x68,
        0xf5,0x12,0xd7,0x15,0x56,0x4d,0x69,0x72,
        0x0e,0xb9,0x2c,0x24,0xcd,0xd7,0x5a,0x8b,
        0x14,0x72,0x41,0x5a,0x20,0x1b,0x3a,0x55,
        0xe7,0x3e,0xab,0x8c,0x9b,0x14,0x63,0x1d,
        0x66,0x35,0xad,0x62,0xc1,0x6c,0x21,0x46,
        0x5b,0x6e,0x1d,0x81,0xe1,0x5a,0xa1,0x45,
        0x37,0x9b,0x70,0xca,0xc3,0x7a,0xee,0x52,
        0xe2,0x50,0xe1,0x5b,0x1c,0xeb,0x57,0x91,
        0x3c,0xad,0xd5,0x6c,0x4f,0x90,0xcc,0x2b,
        0x3d,0xde,0x25,0x3d,0xfc,0x35,0x9f,0x35,
        0x4e,0xf1,0xbf,0x34,0x6a,0x32,0xa4,0xbc,
        0xee,0xcb,0x65,0xdf,0x4d,0x28,0xb8,0x4a,
        0x92,0xc1,0xe1,0xab,0x44,0xd0,0x8f,0x81
    };

    constexpr BYTE prime1[] = {
        0xd5,0x06,0x53,0x6b,0xba,0xd7,0x3e,0x8f,
        0x1d,0xae,0x2c,0xc6,0xb2,0x7c,0x73,0xb8,
        0x83,0xfd,0x5d,0x64,0xf4,0x17,0x77,0xb0,
        0xc8,0x4d,0xb3,0x19,0x19,0xf4,0xad,0xe4,
        0x4d,0x31,0x3c,0xef,0x04,0xc6,0xe8,0xb4,
        0x17,0x9f,0x66,0x4f,0x62,0xf8,0x78,0x03,
        0x39,0xa7,0xa8,0xf1,0x64,0x70,0x86,0x14,
        0x63,0xda,0xe6,0x68,0x98,0x3d,0x29,0x03
    };

    constexpr BYTE prime2[] = {
        0xd4,0x09,0xe2,0x00,0x3e,0x6d,0x55,0x59,
        0x87,0xcf,0xa1,0xee,0xe2,0x5d,0xbc,0x8d,
        0x80,0x43,0x92,0x71,0xdc,0x53,0xa8,0x88,
        0x00,0xc5,0x5b,0xde,0xb2,0x1c,0xb9,0x95,
        0xa7,0x64,0x57,0x0f,0x27,0x88,0xf9,0x31,
        0xab,0x68,0x0c,0xf0,0xfe,0x12,0x76,0x84,
        0xf4,0x09,0x5b,0xc2,0x87,0x0e,0x25,0x73,
        0x99,0x23,0x33,0x26,0x2d,0x8a,0xea,0x29
    };

    char plainText[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    char cipherText[512] = { 0 };
    char plainTextOut[512] = { 0 };

    std::vector<BYTE> publicExponent_bin(std::begin(publicExponent), std::end(publicExponent));
    std::vector<BYTE> modulus_bin(std::begin(modulus), std::end(modulus));
    std::vector<BYTE> privateExponent_bin(std::begin(privateExponent), std::end(privateExponent));
    std::vector<BYTE> p(std::begin(prime1), std::end(prime1));
    std::vector<BYTE> q(std::begin(prime2), std::end(prime2));

    struct MyRSAPublicBlob keyBlob(modulus_bin, publicExponent_bin, 128);
    int numEncryptedBytes = RSA1024_encrypt(plainText, sizeof(plainText)-1, cipherText, sizeof(cipherText), keyBlob);

    struct MyRSAPrivateBlob keyPrivBlob(privateExponent_bin, publicExponent_bin, 128, p, q);
    int numDecryptedBytes = RSA1024_decrypt(plainTextOut, sizeof(plainTextOut), cipherText, numEncryptedBytes, keyPrivBlob);

    return 0;
}
```

The key values in the sample were taken from this output:

```
C:\Projects>openssl genrsa -out private-key.pem 1024
Generating RSA private key, 1024 bit long modulus (2 primes)
.....+++++
......+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)

C:\Projects>openssl rsa -in private-key.pem -pubout -out public-key.pem
writing RSA key

C:\Projects>openssl rsa -in private-key.pem -text -noout
RSA Private-Key: (1024 bit, 2 primes)
modulus:
    00:b0:71:76:5d:ef:1b:6f:3c:f2:de:31:8c:a1:66:
    50:ee:01:96:64:7e:1d:3e:ac:a9:ad:06:31:56:97:
    1d:3c:71:eb:cc:ef:a1:24:b0:b7:0a:33:f7:29:00:
    36:4c:4c:72:d9:88:39:a8:f6:27:c9:24:fc:4d:38:
    b3:03:06:56:e3:fc:67:6a:b3:e2:f1:c1:4a:f9:d2:
    ab:dd:ae:d0:2e:ca:11:41:32:d8:07:ff:3a:b2:27:
    3c:b9:cd:64:4f:bd:23:b6:01:77:33:d8:6f:5a:84:
    aa:9c:21:0b:d8:db:e7:e2:7e:9b:6a:7b:4c:5e:ae:
    1d:da:78:02:87:eb:e6:4f:7b
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    1e:bc:24:fa:47:e4:67:84:1e:6a:46:07:51:36:19:
    72:dc:23:ee:6d:69:7a:b9:68:f5:12:d7:15:56:4d:
    69:72:0e:b9:2c:24:cd:d7:5a:8b:14:72:41:5a:20:
    1b:3a:55:e7:3e:ab:8c:9b:14:63:1d:66:35:ad:62:
    c1:6c:21:46:5b:6e:1d:81:e1:5a:a1:45:37:9b:70:
    ca:c3:7a:ee:52:e2:50:e1:5b:1c:eb:57:91:3c:ad:
    d5:6c:4f:90:cc:2b:3d:de:25:3d:fc:35:9f:35:4e:
    f1:bf:34:6a:32:a4:bc:ee:cb:65:df:4d:28:b8:4a:
    92:c1:e1:ab:44:d0:8f:81
prime1:
    00:d5:06:53:6b:ba:d7:3e:8f:1d:ae:2c:c6:b2:7c:
    73:b8:83:fd:5d:64:f4:17:77:b0:c8:4d:b3:19:19:
    f4:ad:e4:4d:31:3c:ef:04:c6:e8:b4:17:9f:66:4f:
    62:f8:78:03:39:a7:a8:f1:64:70:86:14:63:da:e6:
    68:98:3d:29:03
prime2:
    00:d4:09:e2:00:3e:6d:55:59:87:cf:a1:ee:e2:5d:
    bc:8d:80:43:92:71:dc:53:a8:88:00:c5:5b:de:b2:
    1c:b9:95:a7:64:57:0f:27:88:f9:31:ab:68:0c:f0:
    fe:12:76:84:f4:09:5b:c2:87:0e:25:73:99:23:33:
    26:2d:8a:ea:29
exponent1:
    00:c1:4d:0d:33:ab:86:97:e8:ec:08:d9:ee:af:95:
    c8:b8:3d:65:12:73:82:1f:2d:68:08:4a:a1:62:fc:
    af:8f:7f:a4:20:32:e7:bd:50:f5:66:3e:2d:51:7c:
    66:15:8b:69:79:ce:ce:b9:c4:e7:6a:73:64:2d:05:
    79:11:f4:25:9b
exponent2:
    4a:ec:eb:15:56:f9:df:6c:f1:96:a7:0b:f8:a5:52:
    d9:55:77:8b:29:fc:c6:fb:08:83:ed:39:57:69:ec:
    c8:8f:5f:45:0f:96:65:4b:fb:72:57:b5:3e:cd:71:
    9a:28:93:36:80:90:12:1f:13:1a:9c:cc:82:29:b2:
    d5:e8:fe:71
coefficient:
    16:61:78:25:39:97:45:9d:f0:f1:f1:79:89:48:ac:
    11:8b:1c:bd:00:d4:b1:ed:6f:20:8e:da:6d:ad:8b:
    cf:59:d0:6b:87:6d:44:bd:25:5b:a5:09:99:f5:e1:
    2c:68:d0:e6:8e:6b:e7:bb:8a:b8:fd:d1:0e:d7:c8:
    d6:46:7f:3c

C:\Projects>
```

**UPDATED**

Fixed. As noted in the answer, to get the decryption working correctly, change this line of code from

```
struct MyRSAPrivateBlob keyPrivBlob(privateExponent_bin, publicExponent_bin, 128, p, q);
```

to

```
struct MyRSAPrivateBlob keyPrivBlob(modulus_bin, publicExponent_bin, 128, p, q);
```

Viola! Decryption works!

**OPTIMIZATION**

To speed things up even further by using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm) (CRT) optimization, replace the current            BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB with BCRYPT_RSAFULLPRIVATE_BLOB, then expand
`MyRSAPrivateBlob` to encompass all the following values:

```
BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB
    PublicExponent[cbPublicExp] // Big-endian.
    Modulus[cbModulus] // Big-endian.
    Prime1[cbPrime1] // Big-endian.
    Prime2[cbPrime2] // Big-endian.
    Exponent1[cbPrime1] // Big-endian.
    Exponent2[cbPrime2] // Big-endian.
    Coefficient[cbPrime1] // Big-endian.
    PrivateExponent[cbModulus] // Big-endian.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A private key BLOB contains `BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB` header, public exponent, modulus, prime1 and prime2, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_rsakey_blob#remarks). Notably, the private exponent is *not* included. This is taken into account in the definition of `MyRSAPrivateBlob`, but not in the instantiation of `keyPrivBlob`. The latter must be:

```c
struct MyRSAPrivateBlob keyPrivBlob(modulus_bin, publicExponent_bin, 128, p, q);
```

`privateExponent` and `privateExponent_bin` are not needed at all and can therefore be removed.

With this change, decryption works.

Comment: Works great now! Somehow I was thinking the private exponent (d) was needed to decrypt using this equation: plaintext = ( ciphertext^d ) mod n where ciphertext = ( plaintext^e ) mod n, so I was incorrectly passing the privateExponent_bin. But a BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB requires the modulus instead! So, I assume given these BCRYPT_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB values: public exponent, modulus, prime1 and prime2 it computes (d) thru some maths wizardry. Thanks again @Topaco!

Comment: @vengy - Right, determining private exponent (d) from prime1 (p), prime2 (q), and public exponent (e) is part of regular [RSA key generation, step 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation).